# how to login into a remote site, and download a report in php

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to log in to a remote site, then redirect to a new page once the log-in is successful. On that page, I want to select from a few drop-downs (including one date-range) and then generate a report.

Right now, I have a script which can log in to the site - but I can't figure out how to iterate through the drop-downs. Any suggestions?

```
$url = 'example.co.za/login'; 
$vars = array('username'=>'', 'password'=>''); 

$login = getUrl($url, 'post', $vars); 
$remotePage = getUrl($remotePageUrl); 

function getUrl($login) 
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    if ($method == 'post') 
    {
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
    }
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies/cookies.txt');
    $buffer = curl_exec($ch);
    print_r($buffer3);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $buffer;
}
```

Comment: Similar to your login script, you need another curl request that will generate the report. Figure which request is needed and with which parameters and do it. What exactly is the issue with dropdowns?

Answer (score 0):

When submitting a form programmatically, you don't need to "select" from a dropdown. You can treat it like any other input field and pass a value for the form element. But you should pass one of the values in the dropdown, since that's what the server is expecting to receive.

For a dropdown like this:

```
<select name="weekday">
    <option value="Sunday">Sunday</option>
    <option value="Monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="Thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="Friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="Saturday">Saturday</option>
</select>
```

You can do a POST just like you do with the login form:

```
$vars = array("weekday" => "Friday");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $vars);
```